# How can I generate this schema with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, relational-database

I have a schema for a relational database, which I'd like to generate scaffolding for in my Ruby on Rails 3.2.8 project. I've found the documentation pretty confusing though, and my efforts so far have failed, so my question is exactly how I'd go about generating the needed scaffolding/models for the following schema:

```
USER
name:string
email:string
-----
has_many: posts

TAG
name:string
-----
belongs_to_and_has_many: series
belongs_to_and_has_many: posts

POST
title:string
body:text
-----
belongs_to_and_has_many: tags
belongs_to: user
belongs_to: category

SERIES
name:string
website:string
-----
belongs_to_and_has_many: tags

CATEGORY
name:string
-----
has_many: posts
```

[image: Picture of schema]

Comment: Partly what's been confusing me is what things need to be included in the `rails generate scaffolding` -- do I need to include a `posts_id:integer`? Is it `post:reference`? Many blog posts and questions have different answers, and I don't find the documentation very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go :

```
rails g scaffold User email:string password:string
rails g scaffold Category name:string
rails g scaffold Post title:string body:text category:references user:references
rails g scaffold Tag name:string
rails g scaffold TagsPost post:references tag:references
rails g scaffold Serie name:string website:string
rails g scaffold TagsSerie serie:references tag:references
```

Here I'm using `references` because it has the added benefit of automatically generating an index on the column for you. Although the DB generation is nice, I suggest you review the actual db/migrations files generated and add more indexes etc ...

If you don't want indexes by default, just generate using `model_name_id:integer` like `serie_id:integer` (Note the singular form here)

I'd also consider renaming your association tables to be singular : `TagPost` and `TagSerie` since it's an association between a `Tag` and either a `Serie` or a `Post`

Also beware, when generating automatic rails compliant foreign keys, they'll by default be named `model_name_id` and not `id_users` as your schema mentions. All of this can be changed but it's easier to make Rails figure out everything for you. Convention over configuration is one of the big strength of Rails.

Comment: Brilliant! That works perfectly. I'd like to thank you very much for that -- you've saved me quite a bit of time and trouble.

Comment: Quick question about your use of `Serie` here though -- I believe the correct singular is "Series", as well as the plural. Is the Rails pluralization sufficiently advanced to know that?

Comment: Tried it in a rails console : `pry(main)> "Series".singularize
=> "Series"` Therefore, I believe you should be able to name the model `Series` and expect everything to work, you'll have to test it though :)

Comment: The `singularize` method. Of course Rails has added one to the String class. Well, thanks again!

Comment: And there's `pluralize` too of course! http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-pluralize

Answer (score 1):

I changed a view of your field names so rails can automatically create the table refrences (instead of `id_categories` it should be `category_id` aso...).

```
rails g scaffold user email:string password:string (will most likely be password_digest:string)
rails g scaffold category name:string
rails g scaffold post title:string body:string category_id:integer user_id:integer
rails g scaffold tags_posts post_id:integer tag_id:integer
rails g scaffold serie name:string website:string
rails g scaffold tag name:string
rails g scaffold tags_series tag_id:integer series_id:integer
```

As a personal preference, I would also not use `tags_posts` as a table name, I would call it `tagging`(s) as well as `tags_series` would be `link(s)` or something else.

I recommend you to take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html. It should clear up a lot about naming conventions, models, and migrations.