# Rails schema scaffolding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scaffolding

I have one project for school and I am little bit confused how to make tag and category asociated posts so when I was looking for some tips in google I found this  [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176946/how-can-i-generate-this-schema-with-rails). So I tried scaffolding as described and it was working just fine, but when I ran the server and tried to create new post this appeared:

ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in PostsController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: category, user

So I really don't know what is wrong but I can use some help. Or maybe there can be suggested another way, mabe simpler how to scaffold posts with tags and categories.

Thank you very much

Here are the models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :body, :title, :category, :user
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
end

class Serie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :website
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
end

class TagsSerie < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :serie
  belongs_to :tag
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end

class TagsPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :tag
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password
end
```

Comment: you missed all the association counterparts..for example in Category has_many :posts, has_many :users. Or in the Tag model.. are there all 1:n associations or also n:m? Please fix that first, maybe this removes your error automatically..

Comment: I added those counterparts, but I am stuck to this two errors. In case I have category instead of category_id it says `Category(#36250644) expected, got String(#21132528)` otherwise it says the original `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: category, user`

Comment: can you post your schema and controller + form? got String(#21132528) is also false, because it should be an integer.

Comment: Do you use active_admin, typus or some gem like that? Maybe this could help you: http://ejholmes.github.io/2012/04/22/handling-mass-assignment-with-active-admin.html

Comment: I don't use any admin gems. Mattherick: What schema have you in mind? Controller for posts?

Comment: I mean posts_controller.rb and schema.rb files

Answer (score 2):

Add [`attr_accessible`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible) in your post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id, :user_id, :other_attributes_from_post_model
end
```

Comment: Now this is how my posts model look like :class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :body, :title, :category_id, :user_id, :other_attributes_from_post_model
end

Comment: ..sorry, i forgott to add that it shows the same phrase that I posted before

Comment: so change :category_id to :category and :user_id to :user - if that works, i will update my answer

Comment: @Mythago It would also helpfull to edit your question and paste the Models into it.

Comment: Category(#35822832) expected, got String(#21132528) this appeared when I changed cathegory_id to cathegory, the same with user

Comment: Okay, so please post the model code, as @Mindbreaker already said.

Comment: Ok, edited. I add all models I have for this project. But still don't know how to make it work :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `attr_accessible :category_id, :user_id` in your post model.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Rails creates the scaffolded models with all its attributes non-accessible, so they are not available to edit by an external user.

So, when you tried to create a new Post, the error message raised, as category and user are protected attributes of Post.

You should review your app/models/post.rb and the rest of your models in the same folder to define as accessible those attributes that should be editable by an external user (a web user, for instance).

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id, :user_id
end
```

On the other hand, the so accessible attributes are not protected any more for external edition so you should not use attr_accessible for all of them but just for ones that you will really allow to be modified externally.

Comment: 3.times the same answer :)